# Windows 7 - no administrator account

Tags: windows-7, uac, users

Somehow in the last 24 hours my account has changed to a 'Guest account'.   I am using Windows 7 Professional.

The only application that I installed was GoToMeeting.  I didn't notice anything unusual - it worked fine yesterday.  I installed StarCraft 2 the day before that.

I have only one user account - so I can't seem to log on to any other account.  I didn't notice anything unusual until I tried to edit my keyboard settings (my bluetooth keyboard's function key was not working) - UAC asked me to supply an Administrator password - but there was no way to click yes - or enter a password.

I am trying to stay calm.  I tried scanning for viruses -but it also required UAC elevation so I couldn't.  I can't think of anything unusual - the computer is a fairly new (2 months) MacBook Pro, running in boot camp.

Can anyone suggest anything to try?

----  EDIT -----
additional info:
I entered the boot menu and went into the recovery options.  It asked me for a user login - of course mine didn't work, but it did list 'Administrator' as a choice.  It accepted a blank password, and would allow me to do some recovery options.  If I try to logon as Administrator with a blank password normally - it says that this account has been disabled.  I don't remember ever using it.
A few days ago I setup my system to stop asking me for a password when waking from sleep.  I followed advice on this site:  http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/make-windows-vista-log-on-automatically/  (using the netplwiz command).  I assumed everything was fine - and I did install Starcraft and GoToMeeting since then, so I know I have had normal access in the last 24 hours.
I am thinking of trying to restore to a Restore Point - but don't have any experience with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Safe mode solved this problem.  Apparently Windows 7 has a disabled Administrator account that is 'activated' in safe mode if there are no other Administrator accounts.

I had almost given up - I was starting some backups and prepping to reinstall Windows.  Was really happy to find this fix before that.  I ended up setting up my account and another account as Administrators.

I am looking through the Event logs, running virus scans and trying to identify what caused the User level to change.  Anyway - back to normal ... Wish I had tried Safe mode earlier..

Comment: If Safe Mode didn't work, you could use the Hiren's Boot CD to manipulate the user accounts. Just so you know when you get in a more annoying situation... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Did the workgroup, or domain get changed for some reason?  Did you add it to a new network?  That'll do exactly what you are describing.

Otherwise it sounds like the SIDs or something got messed up somehow.

Anything besides those two installs (sc2 and gotomeeting)?

Comment: no network changes.  It is a home office setup - very basic.  System was up to date with patches and updates.
Your questions made me think of some recent changes that I have done - I added it to my question above.